# Forward HTTPS POST request to Grizzly - Telegram BOT

Tags: ssl, apache2, grizzly, telegram-bot

I'm trying to set a telegram bot up. My favourite language is Java. In the past, I had experience with Grizzly lightweight webserver so I'd like to use it. The problem is that I don't know how to configure the whole environment in order to make it works with SSL.

I configured Apache2 on my Debian machine and it works with an autosigned SSL certificate. So if I browse https://10.0.0.1/ I can see the Apache welcome page.

The plan is to receive HTTPS *POST* requests containing a *JSON* and **forward them to a Grizzly**.

How could I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Easy! With ProxyPass in Apache2!

[Guide followed here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension)